# Callback function in animate method

Tags: jquery, animation

I am using below animation to produce effect for switching to next or previous month in a calendar.Here as visible I have used if-else statements for appropriate animation effects; how can I have my callback function here, so that certain effects are produced after animation is complete.

```
$('.open').each(function (index) {

    if ($('#' + (firstDay + index)).html() < 10) {
        $('#' + (firstDay + index)).animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left + 7,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));

    } else {
        $('#' + (firstDay + index)).animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an animation promise from a jQuery object and use `always()` to callback when all the related animation queues (i.e. on all `$('.open')` elements) are empty.

e.g.

```
$('.open').each(function (index) {

    if ($('#' + (firstDay + index)).html() < 10) {
        $('#' + (firstDay + index)).animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left + 7,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));

    } else {
        $('#' + (firstDay + index)).animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));
    }

}).promise().always(function(){
    // Do stuff here on completion of all animations
});
```

### Notes:

- You can use `done` on animation promises, but, if the animation never starts *(e.g. if it is already in the final state), then it will not fire. Always use `always()` :)
- Your code can be made simple and faster in a few ways. e.g. Use temp vars and not rerun jQuery selectors.

e.g.

```
$('.open').each(function (index) {
    var $control = $('#' + (firstDay + index);
    if ($control.html() < 10) {
        $control.animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left + 7,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));

    } else {
        $control.animate({
            top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
            left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));
    }

}).promise().always(function(){
    // Do stuff here on completion of all animations
});
```

Which reduces further to:

```
$('.open').each(function (index) {
    var $control = $('#' + (firstDay + index);
    $control.animate({
        top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top,
        left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left + ($control.html() < 10) ? 7 : 0,
        }, (400 + (25 * index)));
    }
}).promise().always(function(){
    // Do stuff here on completion of all animations
});
```

Comment: you are an angel..thanx a lot ..@TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

So here it is:

```
$('#' + (firstDay + index)).animate({
    top: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].top, 
    left: pos[firstDayPrevious + index].left + 7,
},(400 + (25 * index)), function()
{
    // callback function
});
```

Comment: That will fire per control... I think he wants overall completion.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie In that case your approach is the way to go.